# how to get parameter value from navigation in react native

Tags: reactjs

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate("ProductDeatils",
      {params:{ price: this.state.GridListItems.price,
        url: this.state.GridListItems.url} 
      });
I wanted to display these params values on the "ProductDeatils" page. please can anyone help me?
```

this.props.navigation.params is undefined.
i tried this
const { navigation } = this.props;
const id = navigation.getParam('price')
not working

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `this` is point to the component rather than the function itself.
2. Which version of react navigation? Have you config `NavigationContainer`, `Stack.Navigator`, `Stack.Screen` well?

Example:

App.js

```js
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Splash"
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
         .......
```

Login.js

```js
export default class Login extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
     console.log(this.props.navigation) // It should work
  }
 .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.I just used this "export default withNavigation(TabOne);" my issue got resolved.